# ternary or something similar for choosing function?

Tags: php, function, ternary-operator

I'm working with Drupal's automated testing in PHP. It's a class that has two methods I'm concerned about: `pass()` and `fail()`. Each one produces a separate line on a results page indicating whether a particular operation passed or failed, e.g.

```
if ( $value == "expected_value" ) {
  $this->pass("Looking for expected value");
} else {
  $this->fail("Looking for expected value");
}
```

What I notice about the above is that it's a bit verbose. I'd like to do something like ternary assignment, only instead where I decide which function to call. Something like:

```
$function = ($value == "expected_value") ? "pass" : "fail" ;
$this->$function("Looking for expected value.");
```

Is this the most concise, elegant way I can phrase this logic? I tried

```
$this->(($value == "expected_value") ? "pass" : "fail")("Looking for expected value.");
```

But I got a parse error. Is there a way to get it down to one line, like ternary assignment?

**Edit** The verboseness that I percieve is not the `if-else` structure, but that I repeat the same message twice. It seems to me that there should be a way of expressing this where I only declare the message once. Of course I could put it in a variable, but that takes up extra space and I pass it twice, also.

Here's another way of framing my question: Is there a way I can define this logic while only expressing `Looking for expected value` one time?

Comment: It seems that you are trying to get conciseness through syntax instead of through design.  Instead of trying to condense your code, make a simple class that can validate the data and automatically call pass/fail.  Try to get the 'generic' code out of the application specific code.

Comment: I agree. By all means, use the ternary as demonstrated in KingCrunch's answer, but doing it to replace the function name itself? Down that way only madness lies. The benefits (which I assure you are entirely perceived, not actual) are not worth even one second of confusion when you open this up in two years and try to figure out just what the hell is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your original code is the best for readability, but if you want something shorter (though not necessarily elegant) you could do:

```
call_user_func(
  array($this,$value == "expected_value"?'pass':'fail'),
  "Looking for expected value."
)
```

Comment: I like this answer because it defines the message only once :)

Comment: Yeah, that's easier than just putting the message in a variable. `</sarcasm>`

Comment: note that you can assign a funtion to a variable ( http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php ). I have aliased GD image functions, HOWEVER I have never tried anything using `$this->` `$foo= $this->bar('baz');`. The idea would be to assign the pass or fail function rather than call it in the test, then call the variable

Answer (score 8):

I would use the usual `if-elseif`-statement, because its the most obvious, readable and (maybe its just me) its not "verbose", its just an `if-elseif`-statement.

However

```
($value == $expectedValue) ? $this->pass() : $this->fail();
```

Comment: I like it, but I still have to type the same pass/fail message twice, or declare it in a variable in a previous line.

Comment: The verboseness that I feel is not the `if-elseif`, but rather that I repeat the same message string twice. It seems to me that there should be a way to only write the argument once.

Comment: Why is the message the same regardless of pass or fail?

Comment: @barfoon because of the way that the DrupalWebTestCase class works. Its output is a table of test cases. Each line is a pass or fail, and there's only one message: "Looking for button..." "Response was 200..." etc. The line is highlight red or green. It keeps you from giving a mixed message, "Successfully did X" when the test failed and that line is red (even though the built-in tests apparently break that pattern IMHO). Even if it's a dumb, yet real-world example, I would like to know alternative ways of expressing this, for learning's sake.

Comment: But the message makes no sense (at least to me): If the test already passed, or failed the test isn't "looking for value" anymore. Its either "value xy passed" or "unexpected value". "Looking for value" sounds more like a message you should return/output _before_ the test runs.

Comment: @KingCrunch The message isn't pass or fail; it's a description of the test. E.g. "Testing for presence of element X" or "Testing for 200 response from web server" -- that message is highlighted in red or green, and either passed or failed. The message is what the test is, not its pass/fail status.